# How to predetermine OkHTTP sha1 hash for Certificate Pinning?

Tags: java, ssl, https, x509certificate, okhttp

I would like to predetermine sha1 hashes for certificate pinning using okhttp CertificatePinner Builder. The [sample code](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/83090befcca69b44c257b96afb519ca66282ca63/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/CertificatePinner.java#L43) mentions to try accessing an https url with a bad pin hash and then review the exception to get the actual hash.

Ideally, if I already new my certificate's signature and chain information by reviewing published certificate public keys and associated sha1 signature I could just take the hash from the public docs or my browser view of the certificate details.

Unfortunately, the "sha1 signature" value displayed for a certificate is in hex format and does not seem to obviously correlate to the sha1 hash shown in the exception.

Is there any way for me to determine the sha1 has to use for Certificate Pinning without going through the exception process?

Also, not sure if the "sha1 hash" to be used for Okhttp is synonymous with a certificate "thumbprint"?

Comment: I also got similar problem. The value displayed is in hex format and converting it to SHA256 via an online tool doesn't help. Did you manage to get it solved?

Answer (score 2):

If letting OkHttp print it for you is too easy, you might prefer using the similar tool that [Moxie Marlinspike wrote](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/blog/authenticity-is-broken-in-ssl-but-your-app-ha/).

Comment: Is there a way to make okHttp print the SHA key in the following format? javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate pinning failure!
   Peer certificate chain:
     sha256/afwiKY3RxoMmLkuRW1l7QsPZTJPwDS2pdDROQjXw8ig=: CN=publicobject.com, OU=PositiveSSL
     sha256/klO23nT2ehFDXCfx3eHTDRESMz3asj1muO+4aIdjiuY=: CN=COMODO RSA Secure Server CA
I am getting it all in hex

Comment: The link changed, here is the new one: https://moxie.org/2011/12/05/authenticity-is-broken-in-ssl-but-your-app-ha.html